# how I change the format of the json array that made by Repository.findAll() in spring boot

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, spring-boot

**I want to change this json list to another format by putting the word "data" before the list and included in Parentheses like I the examples I put it down**
**the rest controller that I use**

```
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
  @GetMapping("/users")
  public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
  }
```

**the response is like that**

```
    [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "test",
                "lastName": "test",
                "email": "tt",
                "createdAt": null,
                "createdBy": "12",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "updatedBy": "12"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "test",
                "lastName": "test",
                "email": "tt",
                "createdAt": null,
                "createdBy": "12",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "updatedBy": "12"
            }
        ]
```

**I want to make it like that**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "email": "tt",
            "createdAt": null,
            "createdBy": "12",
            "updatedAt": null,
            "updatedBy": "12"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "email": "tt",
            "createdAt": null,
            "createdBy": "12",
            "updatedAt": null,
            "updatedBy": "12"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create another model class with `data property

```
public class UserData {

   private List<User> data
   // getters and setters

  }
```

Then change the return type in the controller

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
 @GetMapping("/users")
 public UserData getAllUsers() {
     List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
     return new UserData(users);
  }
```

Or if you don't want to create additional models, you can use `Map<String, List<User>>`

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
  @GetMapping("/users")
  public Map<String, List<User>> getAllUsers() {
  List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
  return Collections.singletonMap("data",users);
}
```